# how can i throttle animations, e.g. set them based on pinch gesture scale

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, velocity.js

I'm using velocity.js to animate css properties.

```
$(".list-element).velocity({
        height: "50px"
    }, {
        duration: 250
    })
```

I would like to change the same properties to the same target value based on dynamic events as well.

Especially pinch gesture (hammer.js) and scrolling.

For that i would need some way to tell velocity that i only want a subset of the full animation.
For example setting it to 10% of the full animation.

Splitting the full animation into x small parts would break the easing i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is very general!
i don't get exactly what you want!
but in Velocity you can use function instead of certain value, like this:

```
var step = 10; //consider it's dynamic variable!
$elm.velocity({
    height: function() {
        return '+='+(step/100)*300+'px';
    }
},whatEver);
```